# asp.net jscript Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just start learning and having this problem while practicing with jscript

Code:

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="jscript">
    function MyClientFunction(sender, arguments) {
        var intValue = arguments.value;
        alert(arguments.value);
        if (intValue % 2 == 0) {
            arguments.IsValue = true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Use Even Numbers");
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:textbox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="MyClientFunction();" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
```

showing error after clicking the "button":

"...Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference..."

I'm not sure how the parameters are passed, not really familiar with how the jscript function works

tried this and no errors:

```
var intValue = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
alert(intValue);
```

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Javascript does not follow .Net's `sender, args` convention.  And `arguments` has special meaning; you should not use it as a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `this`. You don't want to pass anything, you just want to give it the name of your function and the rest will be handled for you:

```
ClientValidationFunction="MyClientFunction"
```

Refer to the example on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx).

Also make sure you're using the correct capitalization. It should be `arguments.Value` and `arguments.IsValid`.

Comment: Yes @defaultuser is what I told you too in the tips.

Comment: Thanks @sbat....! It worked. By deleting the "();", it worked well. Just wanna make myself clear, as mentioned in the MS webpage, we should pass only a "string",i.e, the exact function name, to the ClientValidationFunction? Also, why is the .Value method not showing in the drop down list of the arguments, but still valid to be called? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. :) Yes, just give it the exact name of the function you want it to call, just like you would specify event handlers that are in your C#. The reason there's not a whole lot of intellisense support for JS in this instance is because it's a loosely typed language, Visual Studio can't infer the context in which that method is being called (in other words it's not that smart), and therefore it doesn't know the type of those parameters, and hence the functions/properties it has. Some libraries (e.g. jQuery) will supply documentation specifically for VS, though.

Answer (score 1):

you have a few issues. here's a fixed version

```
<script>
    function MyClientFunction(sender, args) {
        var intValue = args.Value;
        alert(args.Value);
        if (intValue % 2 == 0) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Use Even Numbers" 
    ClientValidationFunction="MyClientFunction" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
```

list of things changed

- add `ControlToValidate` property on the validator, set the value to
  the ID of the control you want it to validate - `TextBox1` in this
  case
- the value for `ClientValidationFunction` should be only the name of a
  javascript function, not an actual call to it
- the function takes two arguments which you have right. I couldn't
  find the definition for the parameter properties. the second
  parameter has `Value` (with a capital V) which is the textbox input
  now that you have associated the controls correctly.
- set `IsValid` true or false within the method
- move the error messages to the validator attribute rather than using
  an alert

additionally I changed `arguments` to `args` since the former is a default name in javascript.

Comment: thanks for such detailed explanation, totally help me in understanding the codes more clearly. I chose @sbat's answer just because he answered it earlier, actually you both had the correct answer...Since I'm new here, not sure if I should choose the answer according to the answering time.. :(

Comment: don't worry about it. usually you pick the one the one that answers your question. if the other answer got things working for you that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing any parameters when calling your client function.
Therefore, both of its declared parameters are `undefined`.

You probably want to pass `this` as a parameter when you call it in the inline event handler.

Comment: That was one of the problems, I didn't know what to pass in the parameters when it's called. Now I put this as parameters, it doesn't show error anymore, but showing msg that the value enter(any values) in the text box is "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because JavaScript is a Case Sensitive language. 
The following code should work:

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="jscript">
    function MyClientFunction(sender, arguments) {
        var intValue = arguments.Value;
        alert(arguments.Value);
        if (intValue % 2 == 0) {
            arguments.IsValue = true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Use Even Numbers");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The explanation is that **arguments** is a parameter object that has two properties as you know (Value and IsValid) and you are referencing is property "Value" with lowercase "v".

Also you need to add the property ControlToValidate to your CustomValidator:

```
ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
```

**the public ClientValidationFunction property of the CustomValidator just expect a valid full name reference to your function in your case you can use just "MyClientFunction" without the function call "();"**. Also all ASP.net validators have a public property called ValidationGroup that is just a label very handy if you have multiple validation regions.

Comment: I tried to correct to upper case, but it didn't work, still the same error. And the .Value and .IsValid methods both didn't appear in different colors from the parameter "arguments" (like the blue color in showing here), they just appear as same color like the variable...

Comment: ohhh you are right, you also need to add ControlToValidate="TextBox1" in your validator.

Comment: Javascript is not a strongly-typed language.

Comment: And he isn't passing anything to the function.

Comment: @rob.alarcon Put ControlToValidate="TextBox1", still showing the same error. Seems like there's no methods .Value and .IsValid, because when I type arguments. and from the drop down list, I couldn't find the methods..

Comment: @SLaks I try with ClientValidationFunction="MyClientFunction(this,this);", it just got the undefined value for arguments

Comment: @SLaks yep ^, I'm tired I guess, what I mean was "Case sensitive"

Comment: @defaultuser are you doing some input? the textbox can't be empty. I delete my example I'm going to do it again, maybe I miss something.